# Drawing connectivity graph on Android

Tags: android, graph, data-visualization, information-visualization

I want to add a connectivity graph, something similar to social network visualization graphs, to my app. Is there any library that I can use to do such thing?

Also I need to have the flexibility to update this graph based on the incoming information or changes that are being made to data.

I want something to make graphs like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPdmW.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent library to display charts and with much customisation.
[MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

Comment: I tried that library but that does not have that kind of capability.